# Replacing $ with \$ in string variable

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I my bash script, I have a string variable with a `$` sign it, and the it isn't escaped. It looks like this:

`x="hello $world"`

Obviously, when I `echo "$x"`, the output is `hello`, since `$world` is being interpreted as a variable. My goal is to modify the string to be `hello \$world`. I tried several techniques, listed below. None of them seem to be working:

`y="$(echo "$x" | sed 's/\$/z/g')"` (outputs `hello`)

`y="$(echo "$x" | sed 's/$/z/g')"` (outputs `hello z`, even though I didn't escape `\` in sed)

Even tried Bash's native string replacement through:

`y=${x//\$/z}` (outputs `hello`)

I realize that I could easily do any of these if the string weren't stored in a variable, but the way my script works, this string will be stored in a variable first, so I need to figure out how to add the `\` after that. I don't care if I create a new copy of the string or edit the same string.

Comment: In your second `sed` command, the `$` (quoted from bash) matches *end-of-line*, as sed works with basic regular expressions.

Comment: *How* do you store the string in a variable? I you do it like you show it, `$world` is gone and you can't get it back, as shown in Toby's answer.

Comment: Contrast your (first) `sed` command with a single-quoted `'$x'` like this: `y="$(echo '$x' | sed 's/\$/z/g')"`.  This version sets `$y` to `zx`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I am using a command (`jq` to be specific) that returns a string that has several unescaped `$` signs in it.

Comment: If you have a string `str` containing an unescaped `$`, like `hello $world` (and it shows up exactly like that when you issue `declare -p str`), doing `echo "$str"` will *not* try to expand the variable name. Can you show your actual assignment?

Answer (score 4):

The assignment (with `$world` empty or undefined) is the same as writing

```
x="hello "
```

Nothing you do to `$x` will see a `$` in there, unless you add it from outside.

Perhaps you meant instead:

```
x='hello $world'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BASH`:

```
x='hello $world'
echo "${x//\$/\\$}"

hello \$world
```

Comment: The question has `x="hello $world"`, not `x='hello $world'` (hence the problem - there's no `$` in `$x`).

Comment: As you already know double quotes will cause variable expansion so we need to use single quote.